# Can I use 4k Dell P2715Q monitor with Thunderbolt 27" on the Retina MacBook Pro 13" (late 2013)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt-display

The [Apple support website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206587) states:

> You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with these Mac computers:
>   MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013) and later

However there is no mention about the type of MacBook Pro Retina, I mean between the 13" which has the Intel Iris Graphics and the 15" which has the Intel Iris Pro Graphics.

If it's not possible to connect both monitors in full resolution at the same time, is it possible at least to just connect a 4k like the Dell P2715Q in full resolution?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154), the 2011 and later MacBook Pro's can support up to *two* [Thunderbolt Displays](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642?locale=en_US) (2560x1440)

The [Late 2013 MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP691?locale=en_US) will support two external displays with a resolution of 2560x1600.

A [4K resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution) is 3840x2160.

So, your MacBook will be able to drive both monitors, the Thunderbolt at full capability and the Dell at reduced resolution.  It won't be able to drive any monitor at 4K

Comment: You mentioned in your comment "will support 4K resolution with either the Iris or Iris Pro Graphics". Now you mention "won't be able to drive any monitor at 4K". Could you clarify? For the latter, did you mean in dual setup only?

Comment: The answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I would add a detail. According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31820048#message31820048), It's able to drive a 4k monitor but at 30Hz only, which appears to be very unpleasant for users. If you confirm, can you update your answer to make me able to accept it?

Comment: It will drive a 4K monitor, but not at a 4K resolution.  The monitor will display at a lower resolution/refresh

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29228615#message29228615), about the late 2013 Retina Macbook Pro 13":

> The rMBP can run 3840x2160 @ 30Hz only (with MST = Secondary) with DisplayPort.

This refresh rate seems to be jittery and unnerving, in addition it can give headaches according to [this user](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29229277#message29229277).